# How does one connect to the RootDSE and/or retrieve highestCommittedUSN with System.DirectoryServices.Protocols?

Tags: c#, .net, directoryservices, adlds

Using System.DirectoryServices, one can get the highestCommittedUSN this way:

```
using(DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://servername:636/RootDSE"))
{
     var usn = entry.Properties["highestCommittedUSN"].Value;
}
```

However, I need to get this information from a remote ADLDS using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, which does not leverage ADSI. Following is a simplified code sample of what I'm attempting to do:

```
using(LdapConnection connection = GetWin32LdapConnection())
{
     var filter = "(&(highestCommittedUSN=*))";
     var searchRequest = new SearchRequest("RootDSE", filter, SearchScope.Subtree, "highestCommittedUSN");
     var response = connection.SendRequest(searchRequest) as SearchResponse;
     var usn = response.Entries[0].Attributes["highestCommittedUSN"][0];
}
```

Unfortunately this kicks back a "DirectoryOperationException: The distinguished name contains invalid syntax." At first I thought there might be something wrong in GetWin32LdapConnection() but that code is called in numerous other places to connect to the directory and never errors out.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to replace RootDSE with domain components. ie: dc=domain,dc=com

Comment: @Zilog - Thanks for the idea. I just found the solution, though. You have to specify "null" for the root container (where I have "RootDSE"). I can't post an answer to my own question until tomorrow, though - so I'll put it up then.

Comment: yes, and SearchScope.Base

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the idea, Zilog.  Apparently to connect to the RootDSE, you have to specify null for the root container. I also switched the filter to objectClass=* and the search scope to "base." Now it works!

```
using(LdapConnection connection = GetWin32LdapConnection())
{
 var filter = "(&(objectClass=*))";
 var searchRequest = new SearchRequest(null, filter, SearchScope.Base, "highestCommittedUSN");
 var response = connection.SendRequest(searchRequest) as SearchResponse;
 var usn = response.Entries[0].Attributes["highestcommittedusn"][0];
}
```

I hope this saves someone else some time in the future.

Comment: Thanks.  I've been spending a lot of time searching for just this solution.  I've implemented it in Java (which uses an empty string to indicate root) but haven't been able to find the .NET equivalent.